# Is it necessary to pass data in JSON format when we use jquery ajax

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am struggling with Jquery ajax. In documentation of Jquery, I notice that they have mentioned to pass data from json format.

However, when I pass it data as normal html format,  I could get the response.

I am worried why then json?

When I try with json,
I get issues with json . When I have to pass lot of html contents such as tables , div and etc,.
I get extra \ characters in the response.

Comment: JavaScript Object Notation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to pass only JSON. You can send and pull almost anything over AJAX. I think your problem is that you're not setting the `dataType` in your `$.ajax` function call.

Comment: when I specify `dataType : "jason"` in ajax function , it won't work. Therefore, I removed that. so where am I wrong?

Comment: It's impossible for us to tell you where you're wrong if you don't show your code.

Comment: It should be `dataType: "json"` not `jason`.